# Image Grid Div won't show up onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a grid of images and I'm trying to show my div **(.thumb-unit)** in an overflowed container **(.work-belt)** onClick...

Jade (HTML)

```
li.art.illustration.animation-element.fade-in
   .thumb-unit(style="background-image: url(/images/giovanni.png)")
   .thumb-overlay
      p Giovanni
```

Javascript

```
function workLoad(){ $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); $('.thumb-overlay').click(function() {
var $this = $(this),
  newTitle = $this.find('p').text(),
  newImage = $('.thumb-unit').show();
$('.project-load').load(newImage);
$('.project-title').text(newTitle);});}
```

**newTitle** shows onClick but **newImage** does not.

Fixed the HTML typo but the variable **newImage** still does not render.

Any ideas? I appreciate it y'all!

Answer (score 0):

Your jaded HTML code is wrong. I will give you a hint :

.thumb-unit(style="background-image: url(/images/giovanni.png--->"<---)

Comment: Thank you. There is also a missing ")" at the end of that line.

Comment: please add the correct html in your answer. It would help him

Comment: Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. From an educational point of view I help him more this way, trust me.

Comment: I think you are more used to rice than fish.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a ' ) ' in your code, after `.png`

It should be :

```
li.art.illustration.animation-element.fade-in
   .thumb-unit(style="background-image: url(/images/giovanni.png)")
   .thumb-overlay
      p Giovanni
```